# How to save Tumblr blog posts to separate files named after blog post title?

Tags: tumblr, backup

Is there an util, web app preferably, to save all public posts to separate files named after blog post titles format?

```
tumblrdir\
    My First Blog Post Title.html
    My Second Blog Post Title.html
    ...
```

Either html or plain text format support is welcome

Answer (score 1):

[**Tumblr Backup**](http://tumblr-backup.fugiman.com/) from *fugiman.com* ([source code is free/libre](https://github.com/Fugiman/Tumblr-Backup/)):

- each post in its own HTML file, grouped in folders by month
- all images in a folder `image`

However, the posts are **not** named by post title. Not all Tumblr post types can have a title (e.g. image posts).

Comment: that is a pity, the posts without title may be saved to file named after date then

Answer (score 1):

See "[Backing up your Tumblr blog to Wordpress](http://quickguide.tumblr.com/post/39780378703/backing-up-your-tumblr-blog-to-wordpress)".

Requires only signing up for a free Wordpress.com blog. Works a treat-there's an option for importing Tumblr, and there are all your posts in order, from the beginning.